# Kotlin how to save each line into Class Objects?

Tags: spring-boot, class, object, kotlin, resttemplate

I receive List from API. And I divided it by lines. I'm not sure How I can save each line into class Objects? Could you help me?
[enter image description here][1]

```
class RecordsList {


    @RequestMapping("/")
    fun receiveAll(): List<String>? {
        val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
        val url = "some URL // doesn't matter"
        val response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String::class.java)

        var lines = response?.lines()
        lines?.forEach { line -> println(line)}
        return lines
    }
}

data class Record(var domain: String, var code: String, var link: String, var other: String)
```

Comment: Also I missed to add @RestController for my RecordsList class in this post. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a variable to store an arrayList of Records.

```
class RecordsList {


@RequestMapping("/")
fun receiveAll(): ArrayList<Record>? {

    // ArrayList to store the `Record`s
    var arrayListOfRecord: ArrayList<Record>? = arrayListOf()

    val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
    val url = "some URL // doesn't matter"
    val response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String::class.java)

    var lines = response?.lines()

    // For each line in the response create a Record object and add it to the 
    // `arrayListOfRecord`s
    lines?.forEach { line -> 
        arrayListOfRecord?.add(
            Record(
                domain = line.domain,
                code = line.code,
                link = line.link,
                other = line.other
            )
        )
    }
    return arrayListOfRecord 
    }
}

data class Record(var domain: String, var code: String, var link: String, var other: String)
```

Comment: It works!!! Thanks a lot! Maybe you can help how I can assign value to Record fields from each line? For example line contains string of values

Comment: Why is the result nullable, when it never returns null?

Comment: Correct, can be changed to !!

Comment: I used the method signature from OP as it was initially returning a nullable list `List<String>?`.